# Automated journalism

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

A webapp called StatSheet got funded today (August 4th, 2010)

http://techcrunch.com/2010/08/04/former-crunchies-finalist-statsheet-recieves-1-3-million-in-series-a/

They are doing 'automated journalism' - using computers to generate human-looking reports of sports games from the statistics

http://www.guardian.co.uk/media/pda/2010/mar/30/digital-media-algorithms-reporting-journalism

Does anyone have any insight into what approach/algorithms are being used to do this / how it might be replicated ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The details for projects like this are a little sparse, but it looks like the baseball summarizer [Stats Monkey](http://infolab.northwestern.edu/projects/stats-monkey/) consists of:

1. **Statistical model**: They build a model of how baseball games typically unfold, most likely by looking at how certain variables (e.g. runs, at bats, etc.) change during the course of a game or differ from what you'd expect to see going into the game (e.g. a no-name team scores more runs than a highly-favored team).  How well a given game fits (or doesn't fit) this model gives them an idea of what might be interesting about that game (e.g. key plays or players).
2. **Text generation**: Given a library of pre-written narrative arcs (e.g. back-and-forth game, come-from-behind victory, etc.) they use the "interesting information" from the model of the game to construct a summary of the game.  I'm not sure, but it looks like they use a decision tree -- conditioned on the information from the model -- to select one of these arcs.
3. **Miscellaneous glue**: This isn't mentioned in their writeup, but there I'd imagine that there are a fair number of hard-coded rules that "glue" the main narrative arcs into a single, cohesive story.

The authors of Stats Monkey have done a fair amount of research in related areas, like website summarization and automatic content aggregation and generation.  Here are a few papers that might be interesting:

- Nathan Nichols and Kristian Hammond.  [“Machine-Generated Multimedia Content.”](http://ndnichols.com/documents/NicholsACHI08.pdf)  *Proceedings of the Second International Conference on Advances in Computer-Human Interactions, 2009.*
- Nathan Nichols, Lisa Gandy, and Kristian Hammond. "[From Generating to Mining: Automatically Scripting Conversation Using Existing Online Sources.](http://ndnichols.com/documents/NicholsICWSM09.pdf)" *The Proceedings of the Third International Conference on Weblogs and Social Media, 2009.*
- J. Liu and L. Birnbaum. 2008. ["LocalSavvy: Aggregating Local Points of View about News Issues"](http://www2008.org/papers/pdf/p1021-liu.pdf). *WWW 2008 Workshop on Location on the Web.*